# Configuration per module in PHP Laminas framework

Tags: php, laminas

I am using Laminas and I have an application with modules such as:

```
/modules
  /moduleA
    ...
  /moduleB
    ...
```

By module, I mean https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/getting-started/modules/.

I would like to be able to have different error handlers depending on inside which module the error was generated/thrown.

I can add a listener for `EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` but any error from any part of the code will reach that listener. How do I add a different listener per module?

For example, for the event `EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR`, I want:

- Exception thrown in `moduleA` to go to `ListenerA`
- Exception thrown in `moduleB` to go to `ListenerB`

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add listeners on a per module basis, maybe someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

The only way I can think of is adding one listener and check which modules controller/action is being dispatched from the route match object. Then you can add different methods for each module. For how to get the module from route match in a listener please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510944/how-to-get-module-name-using-shardmanager-in-laminas/65705266#65705266).